# how to get specific numbers out of string value that is changing ; php

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I'm trying to get latitude and longitude number values out of location info string.

if I search 'hawaii' on the map, the map api returns the string value like below.

$location = {map: geo="**20.471884**,**-157.505**,6" p="Hawaii"}

and I'd like to get latitude and longitude value into $lat, $lng.

How can I make it in php???

Comment: You should use regex.

Comment: `$location` is an string or json encoded data? if it's json then what you shown is incorrect

Comment: use json_decode();

Comment: @stefo91 this is not json

Comment: I've searched and tried code like this and it doesn't work either.  :(   ----
     preg_match('/geo="(.*?),/', $location, $lat);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to match that pattern without the `,6` afterwards, you might use:

```
^{map:\h+geo="(?P<lat>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:,\d+)?,(?P<lon>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:,\d+)?"[^}]+}
```

**Explanation**

- `^{map:\h+geo=` Start of string, match `{map:` and 1+ horizonal whitespaces and `geo="`
- `(?P<lat>` Named capturing group `lat`

  - `-?\d+` Match optional -, 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` Optional part for `.` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group
- `(?:,\d+)?` Optional part for `,` and 1+ digits
- `,` The comma between the values
- `(?P<lon>` Named capturing group `lon`

  - `-?\d+` Match optional -, 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` Optional part for `.` and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group
- `(?:,\d+)?` Optional part for `,` and 1+ digits
- `"[^}]+}` Match " and then until the closing `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RL8gb9/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/gFq4W)

For example

```
$re = '/^{map:\h+geo="(?P<lat>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:,\d+)?,(?P<lon>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:,\d+)?"[^}]+}/';
$str = '{map: geo="20.471884,-157.505,6" p="Hawaii"}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$lat = $matches[0]["lat"];
$lon = $matches[0]["lon"];

echo $lat; // 20.471884
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $lon; // -157.505
```

You might shorten the pattern a bit by recursing the first subpattern using `(?1)`

```
^{map:\h+geo="(?P<lat>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:,\d+)?,(?P<lon>(?1))(?:,\d+)?"[^}]+}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Then if I wanna get -157.505 for longitude without ,6
`$re = '/^{map:\h+geo="(?P<lat>-?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:,\d+)?)?),(?P<lon>-?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:)?)?)"[^}]+}/m';`
is this correct??

Comment: @FlippingFlop You could move that optional part with the comma that you don't want to capture outside of the named group [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pKrJGg/1) Or a bit shorter [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/pKrJGg/2)

Comment: Thanks I've tried it. and got log message on my chrome console 'Uncaught ReferenceError: preg_match_all is not defined'. do I need to make this function or is there any possible problems??

Comment: no it makes error log like comment above :( Do I need to include something to use preg_match_all function?? and my php version is 7.0

Comment: You are running this on the server side in php right? Can you add your code to like for example `https://3v4l.org/` so I can check it?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/tdmCS here it is. It is only part of my php file on server. It has about 450 lines.

Comment: Seems like you are mixing javascript with php. `document.getElementById("latlng");` is javascript, preg_match_all is php. Your file is on the server, but the parts of code are executed in different environments.

Comment: omg I found <script> at the middle of my php file. ;x I'm still very beginner that sorry to waste your time.

Comment: That happens :-) no problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you need:

```
<?php

$re = '/(["\'])(\\\\?.)*?\1/';
$str = '{map: geo="20.471884,-157.505,6" p="Hawaii"}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

test here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e858fca9b0ba65d59919f28ae2a228db5e7610da

Comment: Why all these backslashes? Why do you quantify the group #2? This is also matching `Hawaii` but it is not wanted.